# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in youtube-dl

Tags: bash

I am trying to execute a `youtube-dl` command inside my bash script. The script is as follows :-
`youtube="youtube-dl -prefer-ffmpeg -o $title.%(ext)s ${filename}"`

`eval $youtube`

But I am getting the following error :- 
`syntax error near unexpected token`('

What am I missing here ?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parenthesis are special to the shell, you need to quote them.

```
$ title=foo; filename=bar
$ youtube="youtube-dl -prefer-ffmpeg -o $title.%(ext)s ${filename}"
$ eval echo $youtube
bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('
$ youtube="youtube-dl -prefer-ffmpeg -o $title.%\(ext\)s ${filename}"
$ eval echo $youtube
youtube-dl -prefer-ffmpeg -o foo.%(ext)s bar
```

Or, preferably, save the command in a function instead of a string variable, something like this:

```
ydl() {
    youtube-dl -prefer-ffmpeg -o "$1.%(ext)s" "$2"
}
ydl "$title" "$filename"
```

(except of course that your `eval` method evaluates `title` and `filename` when the string is set, not when the command is executed.)